# RQ job times out

Tags: python, flask-socketio, python-rq

I am trying to accomplish a task by using rq and redis. However the job is sometimes getting stuck importing a module.

```
JobTimeoutException: Task exceeded maximum timeout value (100 seconds)
  File "rq/worker.py", line 812, in perform_job
    rv = job.perform()
  File "rq/job.py", line 588, in perform
    self._result = self._execute()
  File "rq/job.py", line 594, in _execute
    return self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "rq/job.py", line 199, in func
    return import_attribute(self.func_name)
  File "rq/utils.py", line 155, in import_attribute
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "my_task.py", line 13, in <module>
    import my_sockets
  File "my_sockets.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from socketio import socketio_manage
  File "__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/socketio/client.py", line 5, in <module>
    import engineio
  File "__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/engineio/client.py", line 13, in <module>
    import requests
  File "__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 48, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import backend as openssl_backend
  File "cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 2419, in <module>
    backend = Backend()
  File "cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 119, in __init__
    self.activate_osrandom_engine()
  File "cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 163, in activate_osrandom_engine
    with self._get_osurandom_engine() as e:
  File "contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 146, in _get_osurandom_engine
    res = self._lib.ENGINE_init(e)
  File "rq/timeouts.py", line 64, in handle_death_penalty
    '({0} seconds)'.format(self._timeout))
```

It happens only 1 out of 10 times, which makes it hard to reproduce. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Do you get a stack trace when you stop the rq worker with Ctrl-C?

Comment: @Miguel Added the full stacktrace

Comment: The hang occurs during the initialization of the cryptography package. What platform are you running this on?

Comment: @Miguel Ubuntu 18.04 in a docker container

Comment: Same thing here, but Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, not in docker.

Comment: Also happens when I just `import requests`